# how to add after img tag using regex cs6

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I many files of pages which has images in. I need to add a `</center>` after each `IMG` tag. I'm using dreamweaver cs6 and I got this regex so far.

find `<img [^>]+>` and replace `$&</center>`

But it doesnt work. It finds and replaces the `<img>` tags ok but it doesn't add the `</center>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "finds and replaces the `<img>` tags ok", do you mean that after the find and replace, there is no change to the files? As in, it actually did nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how this are done in dreamweaver, but to keep the "found" value you should add \1 - first regexp, \2 second and so on

> `\1</center>`

or try $1 as in htaccess, but \1 is your best bet

Comment: please post an example of the html you want to replace.

Comment: <img  src="/blah.jpg"  alt="blah" /> to <img  src="/blah.jpg"  alt="blah" /></center>

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your regex:

`(<img [^>]+>)`

and this as your replace string:

`$1</center>`

You need to add round brackets to create a capturing group which you can then reference with `$1`.

**NOTE:** Make sure you have changed the `Search` field to `Source Code`, deselected the `Ignore whitespace` and `Match whole word` checkboxes and selected the `Use regular expression` checkbox in the `Find and Replace` dialog.